# How i can list days avaiable in month in array of dates using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of appointments and I need to find all available days in a month by room. An important point is that my appointment have a service and then my array of date and room id.

Below is an example of my schedule object:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "company": {
      "_id": "",
      "fantasy_name": "SAO PAULO AIRPORT MARRIOTT HOTEL"
    },
    "user_id": ObjectId(),
    "status": "pending",
    "service": {
      "type": "accomodation",
      "room": uuidv4(),
      "date": [
        "2024-05-26T15:10:39.538Z",
        "2024-05-27T15:10:39.538Z",
        "2024-05-28T15:10:39.538Z"
      ]
    },
    "created_at": "2023-05-06T16:14:50.566Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-05-06T16:14:50.567Z"
  }
]
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
public async listDaysAvaiableInMonth({ company_id, room, month, year }) {
  const schedule = await ScheduleModel.find({
    $expr: {
      $and: [
        {
          date: { $eq: [{ $month: "$service.date" }, month] },
        },
        {
          date: { $eq: [{ $year: "$service.date" }, year] },
        },
        {
          date: { $eq: ["$company_id", company_id] },
        },
        {
          date: { $eq: ["$service.room", room] },
        },
      ],
    },
  }).exec();
  return schedule;
}
```